# How to visit Bermuda after previously receiving a refusal for a UK visa?

Tags: usa, uk, visa-refusals, ghanaian-citizens, bermuda

I am traveling to Bermuda from Ghana and I understand that I don't need a visa for Bermuda. What I need is an MRV (Multi Re-entry Visa) for the UK or the USA.

I applied for a UK transit visa so I can travel to Bermuda as a special visitor to enter an academy to play basketball and to study. Unfortunately, it got refused for the reason that I haven't proven that I will be admitted to the country I am traveling to, Bermuda. I don't have a visa for Bermuda, as I don't require one. How can I go about my next application?

Comment: One comment I have is that on the [Government of Bermuda website](https://www.gov.bm/comming-bermuda/immigration), MRV actually stands for (is an acronym for) Multi Re-entry Visa, not Machine Readable Visa.

Comment: @CGCampbell could be; I took a leap, as OP was indicating the need for MRV for UK or US, and that as a Ghanian, does not require a visa for Bermuda. I've made the change; TY.

Comment: You don't need a visa (from Bermuda) to visit Bermuda but I understand [from this](https://www.college.bm/index.php/admissions/requirments/international-students) that you need a student Entry Permit, apparently obtained through the school, to study there. If you didn't include evidence of having this with your UK Visa application they may be correct that you might not be admitted.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=GH&DE=BM&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) you are partially correct:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a **multiple-entry visa issued by Canada, USA or the United Kingdom** valid for at least 45 days beyond the period of intended stay in Bermuda for a maximum stay of 3 months.

However, the official [Bermudan government website](https://www.gov.bm/bermuda-entry-visas) states that:

> As of 1 March 2014, Bermuda entry visas and visa waivers will no longer be required **for tourist and business visitors and work permit holders**.

From this we can surmise that student visas *do* require additional documentation. The [Bermuda College website](https://www.college.bm/index.php/admissions/requirments/international-students) confirms this:

> International student Entry Permits will be issued only to persons who are pursuing a full-time course of study at Bermuda College. International students cannot seek employment.

So the proper way to receive a UK visa is to first receive an official study permit from your university of choice.